# Generate random double from random long

Tags: java, random, underflow

in Java I have a random generator that generates random number from -2^63 to 2^63 and that is NOT the java.util.Random.

I need to generate random double in (0,1), this is what I've done so far:

```
return (seed/(double)(9223372036854775807L))/2+0.5;//seed is a random long
```

Is this right? Are there any numerical problem (underflow?)?

Could be better/faster?

Thank  you.

Comment: You can get rid of the `/2` and fold that into the `seed/xxx` part

Comment: No, that would be too great to be a long.

Comment: How can I be THAT stupid? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [Math.scalb](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#scalb%28double,%20int%29) as the most efficient and ensures there is no funny behaviour due to rounding or representation error

```
double d = Math.scalb(seed >>> 1, -63);
```

You can only use 53 bits in a double so some will be discarded.

If you run

```
long seed = Long.MAX_VALUE;
System.out.println(Math.scalb(seed >>> 1, -63));
```

prints

```
0.5
```

With a seed of 0 you get 0.0

With a seed of -1 you get 1.0

Comment: With this: 
        double d = Math.scalb(seed >>> 1, 63);
        return d+0.5;
I'm getting these numbers:
7.60172909551165E27|2.6062896340692396E35|4.0765687952289006E36

Comment: Whit this seed -7545188140698174557
I get this number 1.1819490194320679 (which is greater than 1).

Comment: Its late here. ;) I had a moment of doubt as to whether 63 was right. Can you try now?

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to see just a single division.

```
0.5+(seed/1.84467440737096E+19);
```

That said, you are going to run up against issues with floating point accuracy since you have 64 random integer bits which you then try to squeeze into 53 bits of double precision. You may be better off making a dedicated generator for floating point values, but I could not say for sure since I don't know your motivation.

Comment: I need a large period and usually the generator is used for random long, but I should also implement double random.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way would probably just be to set the first three bits in your long to `0` and then use those bits to make a double.:

```
double rand = Double.longBitsToDouble(seed & 0x1FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFL);
```

This works by forcing the sign to positive, and exponent to be less than 0, which will cause the mantissa to be shifted right at least once. It gives an even distribution assuming all the ints in the long are completely random. Here is a full Java program that uses Random to generate random longs, and then this method to convert them to double's between 0 and 1:

```
import java.util.Random;

class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Random rand = new Random();
        long seed = rand.nextLong();
        double x = Double.longBitsToDouble(seed & 0x1FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFL);
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

This is the output of 10 executions:

```
1.1211565592484309E-247
8.84224349357039E-242
6.956043405745214E-271
3.747746366809532E-232
9.302628573486166E-158
1.1440116527034282E-166
1.2574577719255876E-198
5.104999671234867E-269
3.360619724894072E-213
1.5654452507283312E-220
```

**Edit**

This gives a uniform distribution of all possible doubles between 0 and 1. Since there are many more small doubles you will likely never see a number close to 1. You can fix this by generating a new exponent based on the bits of the existing one, but you need a loop to do it, so it probably isn't the fastest method after factoring this in:

```
long exponent = 0;
for(int i = 52; (seed >>> i & 1) > 0; i++) exponent++;
double x = Double.longBitsToDouble(seed & 0x000FFFFFFFFFFFFFL | ((1022 - exponent) << 52));
```

> 0.4773960377161338
>       0.929045618651037
>       0.7183096209363845
>       0.33962049395497845
>       0.45568660174922454
>       0.11670190555677815
>       0.09371618427480996
>       0.8192870898479095
>       0.9365016017283178
>       0.11311614413193898

Comment: Hum, i've deleted the comment.. the number now are in the range and random.. but are very close to zero.. I should make some more test! :)

Comment: @FabioF. Ah, this evenly and randomly distributes **all** possible doubles between 0 and 1, but since there are much more possible small doubles it gives an uneven distribution in that sense.

Comment: Whao, that's brilliant and terrible .. anyway i'm gettin number greater than 1 (1.3484676232953214, whit this long 9223048428104072362).

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly. I think that easier way is to do the following:
`new Random(seed).nextDouble()`

Comment: @FabioF. But you haven't said you couldn't. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misreading your need  to have a random double from 0 to 1, Java's built in Math.random does just that. So you could avoid all the conversion you are currently doing.